# Logitech Facial Feature tracking

Tags: tracking, feature-detection, logitech

for my application i want to track the facial features. i have tried some methods but none of them provided the required robustness .

the first method is based on haar face detection,canny edge detection, contour finding and key points detection , in this approach the landmarks changes drastically.

second i have used flandmark [[http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/~uricamic/flandmark/]](http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/~uricamic/flandmark/%5d), in this approach the obtained landmark points are not enough(flandmark will detect 7 points).

i have seen the Logitech avatars their facial feature tracking was accurate and robust.any ideas how they are doing ?. it will be helpful....

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/face-detection-and-tracking-using-the-klt-algorithm.html) in matlab. It uses the Viola and Jones algorithm to detect a face, and Kanade-Lucas-Tomasi (KLT) point tracking algorithm to track it.